# Classification of time series according to linearity, ergodicity and stationarity

Tags: time-series, linear-model, stationarity, ergodic

I'm new to the subject of Time Series and I have some difficulties understanding some cross definitions:

1. Linear and non-linear time series
2. Ergodic and non-Egordic time series
3. Stationary and non-stationary time series.

By cross definitions I mean the relationships between them. Is there any reference with a general framework to classify the time series according to the 3 items above? Some questions are pertinent and easy to ask:

- What is the definitive mathematical definition of linearity?
- Is each linear time series an ergodic TS?
- Is each linear time series an sationary TS?

Comment: I will add a comment. Not all linear or stationary time series is ergodic. For example, two dimensional Brownian motion is not ergodic even though 1 and 3 dimensional are.